# CSS view changes after addition of bootstrap

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I'm a beginner in web development. I am making a simple todo list app. I have designed a webpage which changes after addition of bootstrap.

**Code without bootstrap**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>To Do List </title>
  {% load static %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'todo/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<body>

<div class="utils_box" id="heading">
<h1>{{kindOfDay}}!</h1>
</div>

<div class="utils_box">
{% for i in newListItems %}
  <div class="utils_item">
    <input type="checkbox" \>
    <p>{{ i }}</p>
    <a href="{% url 'todo:delete_item' i %}">X</a>
  </div>
{% endfor %}

<form class= "utils_item" action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="Add new item here">
<button type="submit" name="button">+</button>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[Image of webpage without bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC5Lk.png)

**Code with bootstrap**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>To Do List </title>
  {% load static %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'todo/styles.css' %}">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  
</head>
<body>

<div class="utils_box" id="heading">
<h1>{{kindOfDay}}!</h1>
</div>

<div class="utils_box">
{% for i in newListItems %}
  <div class="utils_item">
    <input type="checkbox" \>
    <p>{{ i }}</p>
    <a href="{% url 'todo:delete_item' i %}">X</a>
  </div>
{% endfor %}

<form class= "utils_item" action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="Add new item here">
<button type="submit" name="button">+</button>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[Image of webpage after adding bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6ver.png)

Edit2: Added CSS code for reference.

**CSS code**

```
html {
  background-color: #E4E9FD;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(65deg, #A683E3 50%, #E4E9FD 50%);
  min-height: 1000px;
  font-family: 'helvetica neue';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.utils_box {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#heading {
  background-color: #A683E3;
  text-align: center;
}

.utils_item {
  min-height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
}

.utils_item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

input:checked+p {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-decoration-color: #A683E3;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin: 20px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #00204a;
}

form {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

button {
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: #A683E3;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  border-width: 0;
}

input[type="text"] {
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  top: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  width: 313px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 0 #A683E3;
}

::placeholder {
  color: grey;
  opacity: 1;
}

footer {
  color: white;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible that Some names of your classes match the names of the classes in Bootstrap, it might be that bootstrap is overwriting your styling. try to change the names of your classes using more than one word. for example:

```html
<div class="utils_box" id="heading">
<h1>{{kindOfDay}}!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: did you change the name of classes in your css file ? please share your css code !

Comment: You can use your browser e.g. firefox and inspect the elements: ... right click ... see menu point. You can see there any element with related css source

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap by default sets the background colour to white.
You can override it by using

```
body{
  background-color: transparent !important; 
}
```